# How to open link mailto:address@domain.tld to adress@domain.tld instead of instead of //domain.tld in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: email, xamarin.forms

## Initial info

Using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2019 Community on Windows 10.

I have an About page on my app, that links to client's address, phone number and email.

I am a complete beginner in mobile app development. I only created one more or less identical app before this one and before the soon-to-be-mentioned update.

## Before:

I used `Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(url))` before and all links worked fine ie. the above-mentioned links opened in Google Maps, Phone Caller App and Gmail respectively.

As of Xamarin.Forms version 4.3.0 `Device.OpenUri` is obsolete.

### In-between move:

I replaced my `Device.OpenUri` with `Launcher.TryOpenAsync` from Xamarin.Essentials.

None of the links did anything.

## Now:

Instead I replaced it with `Browser.OpenAsync(new System.Uri(url), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred)`

Link to goo.gl/maps address opens Maps app at the correct address. Good.

Link to "tel:+99912345678" opens Caller at the correct phone number. Good.

Link to "mailto:address@domain.tld" opens Gmail (good), but the recipient is `//domain.tld` instead of `address@domain.tld`. Bad.

## Code:

#### AboutViewModel.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace Domain.ViewModels
{
    public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public AboutViewModel()
        {
            Title = "About";
        }
        public ICommand ClickCommand => new Command<string>((url) =>
        {
            //Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(url));
            //Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new System.Uri(url));
            Browser.OpenAsync(new System.Uri(url), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        });
    }
}
```

#### AboutPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Domain.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Domain.Views.AboutPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        ...
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="Street" >
                            <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="https://goo.gl/maps/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
                            </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Span>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        ...
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="+999 (0)12 345 678" >
                            <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="tel:0099912345678" />
                            </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Span>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        ...
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="address@domain.tld" >
                            <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="mailto:address@domain.tld" />
                            </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Span>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        ...
```

#### AboutPage.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Domain.Views
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AboutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

Where my error lies in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class AboutViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public AboutViewModel()
    {
        Title = "About";
    }
    public ICommand ClickCommand => new Command<string>((url) =>
    {
        //Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(url));
        //Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new System.Uri(url));
        if (!url.Contains("mailto"))
        {
            Browser.OpenAsync(new System.Uri(url), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }
        else
        {
            _ = SendEmail("Test mail subject", "This is tesing mail body ", new List<string>() { url });
        }
    });


    public async Task SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> recipients)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new EmailMessage
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                To = recipients,
                //Cc = ccRecipients,
                //Bcc = bccRecipients
            };
            await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fbsEx)
        {
            // Email is not supported on this device
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Some other exception occurred
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

Comment: This worked perfectly. For those as unknowledgeable as I am: you have to add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;` for `Task` and `List` to work. I also added this line `url = url.Substring(7);` just before the `_ = SendEmail("", "", new List<string>() { url });` line to get rid of `"mailto:"` beginning of the url. Answer upvoted and accepted. TY